# How can I upgrade the Typescript version used by React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using `import type` declarations in my React Native code, which works fine with `npx tsc` and inside of VS Code.  But when I run the app, I get Unexpected Token errors.

How can I get React Native to play nicely with `import type`?  It seems to me it must be using an old version of TypeScript but if I knew how to configure that, I don't recall how now.

(I've tried resetting cache, deleting app from simulator and reinstalling, cleaning Xcode build.)

Edit: I'm thinking this may have to do with an old version of @babel/plugin-transform-typescript, which is part of metro-react-native-babel-transformer, which is required by RN's package.json.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by upgrading to React Native 0.63.1.

I had previously tried upgrading just @babel/plugin-transform-typescript but that didn't work - it seems something else bundled with RN 63 is needed to play well with TS 3.9.

Answer (score 2):

In order to specify the version of a package used by one of your project's dependencies, you can add a `resolutions` block to your package.json:

```
 "resolutions": {
    "react-native/@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "<version number>"
}
```

Comment: I tried upgrading plugin-transform-typescript to latest (and metro-react-native-babel-preset, which includes it) but no luck so far.